# Executing Selenium tests in Jenkins and export Test Result in TestLink

Tags: jenkins, selenium-rc, testng, jenkins-plugins, testlink

I'd like to run Selenium tests with Jenkins and export results in TestLink.

I followed this tutorial : https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/TestLink+Plugin

I managed to run tests from jenkins and exported the result in TestLink but only the test example which did not use selenium.

When I replaced it by a selenium-made test (exported in "Java TestNG RC") I got some errors at compilation ("class, interface, or enum expected","illegal character","illegal statement", ...)

Do I have to install a plugin for selenium or something else?

Help is appreciated.

Comment: what tutorial you are talking about? I don't see any link.  Can you show us some code snippet where you are getting problem?

Comment: Sry for that mis, i meant this tutorial 
https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/TestLink+Plugin

Comment: Next time you have to make changes to question don't throws them in answers, SO gives ability to update or edit your question anytime you want.

Answer (score 0):

My experience is that you cant trust the code that the IDE creates.  I throws a lot of stuff in there that is just not useful.  I work in ruby and the first time I tried to run a piece of code exported from the IDE it failed miserably.  Its not surprising that it wont compile in java.  You are better of coding it yourself.  The IDE is a good tool to learn concepts but you really need to move beyond it fairly quickly.

The IDE will assume that you want to run the tests in a Unit framework such as JUnit or TestNG.  Have you been able to run this test or any others in the testNG framework?

I would recommend starting with selenium and then build on that.  It takes a lot of tools to create a solid CI environment and they are all complicated.

Comment: Thx for ur answer. In fact i can run testng, and i just tried to run a sélénium test which search on google, but the exported test ( format java testng rc) doesn t contains any instance of selenium or DefaultSelenium , i dońt Know How to make this test run...

Answer (score 0):

In fact i ran tests  in TestNG well, the issue is with Selenium.
I don't know how to do if i have to import classes in the test.java or if i have to put something in my workspace ...

here is an example of a test very simple :

```
package com.example.tests;

import com.thoughtworks.selenium.*;
import org.testng.annotations.*;
import static org.testng.Assert.*;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class try extends SeleneseTestNgHelper {
    @Test public void testTry() throws Exception {
        selenium.open("www.google.fr");
        selenium.waitForPageToLoad("30000");
    }
}
```

and the errors i got :

```
error: package com.thoughtworks.selenium does not exist
error : cannot find symbol (i got this one about 17 times).
```

i think i have to put  selenium-java somewhere but i don't know where ...

Comment: This seems obvious but do you have the [Selenium client driver](http://seleniumhq.org/download/) installed?

Comment: What do u mean by installed ? This contains only Jar files ?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the way it works in Java but in Ruby to use Selenium I need to do something like this. **require "selenium-webdriver"** In ruby its managed in a gem.

Comment: @AloysFortier You have to add your selenium jar into referenced library. This will definitely solve your issue. Also make sure you have TestNg on your machine.

Comment: I added sélénium depedancies to my pom.xml file, i have no more errors but the test is not run at all...

Comment: When i fill the custom field "java class" in testlink , i have the java class exemple for test, but MY tests are not class only java file . I think the path to my test is no good ...